# Is it possible to join a Microsoft Teams, zoom or Google Meet call as a bot and record

Tags: webrtc

I would like to know if it is possible to join a MS Teams, Google Meet or Zoom Meeting via the URL as a bot and record the video/audio from the call.

Is this possible using WebRTC. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to joins a Teams call with a Bot (start with the samples here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples). It's not possible to join a Teams call with standard WebRTC mechanisms even though it is being used under the hood. No idea about Meet or Zoom.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [neko](https://github.com/m1k1o/neko) to do this. It is a headless Chromium instance that you can run on a remote server. I join my call using this headless instance.

Neko uses GStreamer so you can send things out via RTMP [hasn't been merged to master yet](https://github.com/nurdism/neko/issues/54) but I bet you could also easily update to save the video frames to disk!

Making it into a bot will be a little harder though. You will have to script interaction with each site. Chrome has nice plugins to script site interaction, possibly that could solve the issue?